# ModuleNotFoundError, but it runs in anaconda (jupyter)

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I've installed a module named [rauth](https://rauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) through terminal with `pip3 install rauth` command but when I import the module and run the code on Visual Studio Code with python3 interpreter, it gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rauth'` error. But it is indeed installed and I can use it in Anaconda. The package file is stored  here.

`/Users/puffedricecracker/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rauth`

And it seems like all my pip installed packages are stored in that path, but those are imported outside Anaconda with no problem. Tried several other commands as google search suggested.

• `pip install` instead of `pip3 install`

• `python -m pip install`

• `python3 -m pip install`

Let me know if there is any other information needed to be specified.

Comment: I've read both answers below and I just wanted to point out that you may not have fully understood what virtual environments are. They are a great & necessary feature of Python in general and conda in particular and are worth reading up on. Here's a short introduction https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: @orangeInk That's a kind step-by-step article! I didn't succeed in using venv in visual studio (My newly created venv is just not showing up...) but see why it is helpful to have venv in the future. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

this is due to the module is installed into site-packages in Anaconda but not Visual Studio. Can you check if the module exists in Visual Studio folder? Another way to test it is to open Python IDLE and run the import, it should also return an error.

Comment: Thank you for help! And you were right, I couldn't import it in Python IDLE. But upon searching where packages usually go, it seems like Visual Studio Code doesn't have any package file in it. I manually found the path and installed the package there.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help! And seems like you found the way to change installation path!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this could be an universal solution but there was a way to set where to install a package using pip.

1. In python shell, find where your python modules usually go. It seemed like most of pip installed packages were installed in the second path so I chose that.

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.__file__)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/re.py

>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> print(sqlalchemy.__file__)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/__init__.py
```

2. Uninstall the package using `pip uninstall packagename`
3. Reinstall with a path name.

```
pip install packagename -t /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

(In fact, just copy pasting package files (in my case, they were rauth, rauth-0.7.3.dist-info) from anaconda package path in the post worked.)